# ssh-key metadata doesn't work after image capture/boot on centos 8

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have a program that creates instances from upstream CentOS images, using the `ssh-keys` metadata to log in. This works, so long as I'm booting from an upstream image, like `centos-cloud/global/images/centos-8-v20210217`:

```
            metadata: {
              "items": [
                {
                  "key": "block-project-ssh-keys",
                  "value": "true"
                },
                {
                  "key": "ssh-keys",
                  "value": "centos:" + ssh_key + " centos\n"
                },
              ]
            },
```

The problem is in shutting down this instance, capturing an image, and starting a new instance *with new keys* in `ssh-keys` metadata. This does not seem to write new keys at all, and furthermore, my attempts to use the in-browser SSH (which would create a user by my name) does not work either (error 15). That feature has worked for me in the past when booting from the upstream image as well.

The only way I've been able to get is by logging in with the old keys. Other than that, the instance is normal.

The problem persists even as I try to manipulate keys in the browser, and they are accepted by https://console.cloud.google.com/

I have tried a few things to rectify this, including truncating the `/home/centos/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, removing the `/home/centos/.ssh` directory, and even the whole user with `userdel --remove --selinux-user --force centos`, under theory that attempt to use the same user twice might conflict some Google software.

I also took a look at the logs in the `google_osconfig_agent` service: nada.

Am I missing a trick somewhere? At least on Azure, one is theoretically obligated to "generalize" an instance (a program idiomatically is provided to do that, it mostly deletes the user and scrubs keys on Linux). Amazon has no equivalent, always running an arbitrary short shell script of your choice, it's up to you to get whatever you want done therein.

Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Even though the metadata was wrong, there is something else that is also incorrect in your handling of ssh keys. The key to debugging problems is knowing the precise state of what you are trying to debug. Your question does not have the low level details required to answer.

Comment: I mean, I imagine the thing that is probably wrong is that the google agent responsible for munging keys doesn't like to deal with an instance with some state already present, there must be way to clear it.

Comment: 1/2) I have never personally seen your problem. SSH keys are stored in the "users-name/.ssh" directory in the file authorized_keys just like your question states. If you delete the entire file, that user will not be able to login using keypairs. You can edit that file and just remove a single keypair.

Comment: 2/2) If there is a bug with Google's handling of keypairs, you should be able to reproduce that bug using the CLI: `gcloud compute instances add-metadata --metadata-from-file`. Login to your instance using one user-id and then manipulate a different user-id with the CLI. Then check what happens with the authorized-keys.

Comment: Right, but the point is it works when I boot and have a user created fresh, doesn't work after capture-and-boot. Messing around in the portal to add and remove keys is likewise ineffective. And somehow, seems to break the in-browser SSH as well.

Comment: Compare the state of the ssh authorization in both instances.

Comment: So, is your experience that after a capture that google will just overwrite whatever content is in .ssh/authorized_keys, even if the user exists, even if the file exists and is non-empty, if booting from a captured image that had the user created via metadata already?

Comment: I use images constantly and I have not seen your problem. As I commented, your metadata is wrong and I suspect there is something else wrong with your process. However, you have not provided the low level details, so we can keep guessing and commenting. Sometimes you have to dig in and analyze the details to see what is actually configured. Doing that research is your job.

Comment: Chill dude. What would have been helpful would to have told me the programs that execute these scripts. I have found the problem, I think: I have swapped rsyslog for syslog-ng, and for whatever reason, google-compute-engine takes a hard dependency on rsyslog, and gets upset when I use yum swap. I will report this anti-feature to the maintainers, if I can find them.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by this image build using syslog-ng. It so happens that the RPM `google-compute-engine` takes a hard dependency on `rsyslog`, so, removing rsyslog will likewise break a bunch of stuff.

I don't have a solution to continue to use syslog-ng quite yet, I will probably be taking apart the package to see why it takes a hard dependency on rsyslog and if it can be effectively ignored.

This has been filed here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/897

I added a more thorough writeup here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-configs/issues/20